# Realm lexical or preprocessor 'RLMAccessor.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, realm, ocmock

I wanted to write some unit tests using **GRUnit** & **OCMock** for an app using **Realm**. Even though the pods are installed and the paths should be correctly set, Xcode can't seem to find a number of files like RLMAccessor.h.

I get an "**lexical or preprocessor issue**"

I've tried a bunch of things like removing realm, downgrading, updating cocoapods, clearing the cache, adding the libraries and so on but nothing
seemed to work.

**Anyone been able to set up Realm to work with GRUnit?**

**EDIT** this how my pod file's set up. I'm using cocoapods but including real/headers didn't work for my test target.

```
target: myApp do
    pod 'Realm' , '~> 0.92.2'
    pod 'Localytics', '~> 3.1.1'
end
    target :test do
      shared_pods
      pod 'Realm/Headers'
      pod 'GRUnit', '~> 1.0.1'
      pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.2.1'
    end
```

Using Realm 0.92.2, Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: Could you please share your `Podfile`, and see if your setup differs from what is recommended at http://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#cocoapods-install ?

Comment: @segiddins added an edit. I followed the realm directions to install realm via cocoapods but somehow it does not find the headers for my test target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by upgrading to a newer GRUnit version then downgrading agin because GRUnit didn't work anymore and removing pod 'Realm/Headers' with pod 'Realm' and ran pod install again.